# Gerar uma string que contém apenas os números de outra string em php

Tags: php, string

Fiz a seguinte função em php que recebe uma string, e retorna uma nova string contendo apenas os números da string recebida.

Só que não estou conseguindo concatenar cada número à essa nova string. Eu tentei o seguinte:

```
function extraiSoNumsDeString($string){
    //Definindo uma String
    $result="";
    for($i=0; $i<strlen($string); $i++){
        $j = substr($string, $i,1);
        if ($j>="0" and $j<="9") $result=.$j;
    }
    //Retorna uma string contendo apenas o número da conta.
    return $result;
}
```

Só que o interpretador acusa erro de sintaxe nessa linha:

```
if ($j>="0" and $j<="9") $result=.$j;
```

dizendo que eu não posso usar esse ponto para concatenar $j a $result.

Alguém sabe como eu poderia fazer essa concatenação? Eu preciso obrigatoriamente retornar uma única string nessa função...

Comment: Não seria `.= $j` ao invés de `= .$j`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Como apontado no comentário o erro de sintaxe está na posição do ponto. O uso correto desse [operador de atribuição](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.operators.assignment.php) é `.=`

```
function extraiSoNumsDeString($string){
    $result="";

    for($i=0; $i<strlen($string); $i++){
        $j = substr($string, $i,1);
        if ($j>="0" and $j<="9") {
            $result .= $j;
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Existem formas melhores de chegar no mesmo resultado com uma regex:

```
$conta = '123 123.321-23';

// Casa tudo que não é numero \D e substitui por nada
echo preg_replace('/\D/', '', $conta);
```

Veja [funcionando](https://3v4l.org/t3BS7).

Answer (score 3):

Amigo, você pode fazer da seguinte forma:
Essa é uma função PHP que deixa apenas números em uma variável.

```
function apenasNumeros($str) {
    return preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $str);
}

//$filtrar = apenasNumeros("vamos 45testar45////321");
//echo $filtrar;
```